# Angular seperate first name last initial

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular. I currently am using ng-repeat to display my data from a rest endpoint. I want to have the name field not be the full name but rather - First Name - Last Initial. Example:

John Doe -> John D.

Comment: This is simple javascript. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

this is simple, just with javascript

use [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var name_full = 'John Doe'
var name_array = name_full.split(' ');

name_array[0] + ' ' + name_array[1].charAt(0) + '.'; // "John D."
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a method and use it in your project.

```
public customName (name) {
   let newName = name.split(' ');
   newName = newName[0] + ' ' + newName[1].slice(0, 1) + '.';
   return newName; 
}
```

Below is an example of how the code will work.

```js
const customName = (name) => {
   let newName = name.split(' ');
   newName = newName[0] + ' ' + newName[1].slice(0, 1) + '.';
   console.log(newName); 
}

customName('John Doe');
```